# How to show jQuery popup in Different List

Tags: jquery, popup

I need to help for that.. when I click on .btm-arrow class i want to only that's popup box show. But now it show every popup box.
I used in class attr that's why its conflict.

**Html Code**

```
<div class="TableData">
<ul>
<li>SURAT AL-FATIHAH</li>
<li>SURAT AL-FATIHAH</li>
</ul>
<p><input type="text" name="#" placeholder="Type Your Item"></p>
</div>
<a href="#">
<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down btm-arrow" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
$('.btm-arrow').click(function(){
$('.TableData').toggle();;
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: please provide more details. What do you mean when you said other popup box? Which others?

Answer (score 0):

You can find this solution using **closest()** and **prev()** methods of jquery.

```
 $('.btm-arrow').click(function(){

    $(this).closest("a").prev().toggle();;
 });
```

**Working example you can find here - https://jsfiddle.net/20rx1nvp/2/**